# Creating cloud storage for android app

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

I am creating an android app for university which has cloud storage so when the teacher sends a note the student can view it without download it

I want to know if their is any book or tutorials for creating your own cloud storage for android

Comment: If the teacher sends a file to the cloud and you want to see it you have to download it.

Comment: Thank u for your reply Ok so are their any book or tutorials that can help me with this

Comment: No, to view it doesn't mean to download it. Google Cloud Storage can serve content directly.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use Google Cloud Storage to store your data. [To learn more about GCS, you can check this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs).

You will need to have a Google Cloud Storage bucket tied to an App Engine application you are going to develop. From your android code, you will want to call the Cloud Endpoints API for your application to retrieve the data from GCS.

[For more info about Cloud Endpoints for Android, you can check this link](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/google-cloud-endpoints-for-android/).